# HTTP vs HTTPS communication over Azure Private Endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

From what I understand, private endpoints effectively bring a service in your own vnet. Then, if no one from the outside world can access that service, is HTTP communication over private endpoints safe? Or is HTTPS recommended?

Comment: "no one from the outside world can access that service" -- this is really never known, especially when you don't own the network. If you care about confidentiality, always encrypt

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS should be the default today if you don't have any extraordinary reasons to not use it.